# Why Eclipse doesn't have path to java compiler?

Tags: java, eclipse

As I know, java source code is compiled into class files by the java compiler (javac.exe); then these class files are put into JVM to interpret using java.exe

But Eclipse is only using javaw.exe. So, I think javaw.exe is equivalent to javac + java

But some references say javaw.exe nearly equivalent java.exe. thus Eclipse only has the interpreter progress. Compiler process takes place where, how?

How should I understand this?

Comment: javaw.exe is just a version of java.exe that doesn't show a console window.

Answer (score 7):

1. Eclipse does not compile files using `javac`. It has its own, independent implementation of a Java compiler, complete with its own set of error messages—and bugs.
2. Eclipse still needs access to all the standard library classes against which it compiles Java code.
3. The Java runtime which runs the Eclipse IDE process is not related to the JDK used to compile the code against. For all that matters, Eclipse could be a native application written in C++ and that wouldn't stop it from being able to compile Java.

Comment: Thank @Marko Topolnik. I am new in Java, so i have many question.
So, Eclipse does not using javac compiler because it has its own, but it still need Java library class and tool such as javaw to interpretive class file?

Comment: `javaw` is irrelevant to Eclipse's compiling. It is used to run Eclipse itself because Eclipse happens to be a Java application itself.